# Xml InnerXml indentation issue

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, indentation

I have a `XmlDocument` like this:

```
<Root>
  <Settings>
    <PresentationSettings>
    </PresentationSettings>
  </Settings>
</Root>
```

When I set the `InnerXml` of `<PresentationSettings>` with this text...

```
<Desktop>
  <WidgetElements>
    <WidgetElement Name="1">
    </WidgetElement>
    <WidgetElement Name="2">
    </WidgetElement>
  </WidgetElements>
</Desktop>
```

..., the output file is saved like this:

```
<Root>
  <Settings>
    <PresentationSettings>
      <Desktop>
  <WidgetElements>
    <WidgetElement Name="1">
    </WidgetElement>
    <WidgetElement Name="2">
    </WidgetElement>
  </WidgetElements>
</Desktop>
    </PresentationSettings>
  </Settings>
</Root>
```

It seems that the root of the `InnerXml` (i.e. `<Desktop>`) is starting from the right indented column, but rest of the `InnerXml` preserves it`s original indentation. I tried a lot of methods, but all of them are giving the exact same output. The methods I tried were:

- `XmlTextWriter` with `Formatting = Formatting.Indented`.
- `XmlWriter` with `XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }`.
- Converting to `XDocument` with both the above methods.
- Using `XmlDocumentFragment`.

Can anybody point me in the write direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: White space is not significant in XML - why are you trying to "solve" this issue?

Comment: I am a little nuts about things being in perfect order. :P Although it will hardly affect my application, but I still want to know that why is this happening, and how can it be fixed.

Comment: It is happening because whitespace is not significant to XML - it doesn't matter so why waste code and CPU cycles on it?

Comment: Sometimes things like wasted code/time/CPU cycles, or no affect on execution do not matter. But the correct output does.

Comment: That's my point. It _is_ correct output.

Comment: For me the *correct* output means *property indented xml*. I asked this question not to discuss about perspectives, but why the code was not getting indented properly. No offense meant, but you are getting into useless arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use XDocument or XElement, XmlDocument is .Net 2.0 aka antiquated.

Instead write:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse("<Root><Settings><PresentationSettings></PresentationSettings></Settings></Root>");
XElement pSettings = root.Element("Settings").Element("PresentationSettings");
pSettings.Add(otherContentXml);
root.Save(fileName);
or
string formattedXml = root.ToString();
```

Comment: I know I can use XElement to do it, but the library is too big to translate to 4.0. But still, as this is the correct answer, which I too know (:P) I am accepting it. BTW, `pSettings.Add(otherContentXml);` will convert the `<>` signs to &lt; and &gt;. You need to add a `XElement` passed from the string.